# How to key trap in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

i am just a newbie in programming. i want to know on how to key trap a letter or a number in a text box. example, there is a text box about age, the user will not type a letter on that text box. And also, i want to know how to limit number of characters that will enter on that text box. example, there is a text box about grades, the user cannot type 1111 on grades. I am using c#, asp.net and sql server 2008 for database. an example is enough for me. thanks

Comment: Best approach is using javascript or jquery functions

Comment: for example, onkeypress event will check every inputted symbol, and if it is not number, it will delete it and show an notification to the user

Comment: @Khazratbek where can i find the onkeypress event ?

Comment: google: w3c input number
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp 
Look for "Input Type: number"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is inputting only numbers:

```
<style>
    #errmsg
    {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //called when key is pressed in textbox
        $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {
            //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
            if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                //display error message
                $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
                return false;
             }
         });
     });
</script>

Number : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg"></span>
```